# bitcoind sendfrom round amount error

Tags: bitcoind

I have problem with bitcoind with the command sendfrom

Example :

./bitcoind sendfrom test1  1.99990005

The value when command "listtransaction test1" is 1.99990004.

I'm using bitcoind in ubuntu 12:04 locale en_US.UTF-8

Thanks for help.

Comment: @NateEldredge: The one Satoshi difference between the two amounts would appear to be the problem.

Comment: What version of bitcoin?

Comment: My version is 0.8.6

Comment: I've tried this on testnet and I've been unable to reproduce this with 0.8.6. 1.99990005 is always parsed as 1.99990005. What CPU architecture? Have you compiled from source or using the precompiled executable?

Comment: To avoid ambiguity by using doubles and floating point numbers, IMO we should switch to decimal strings instead of numbers for monetary amounts in the RPC interface. See https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/3759